# Using an inline form directive multiple times to update to an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to be able to have multiple inline forms that update into one array after they are saved. They also need to be able keep their values and not reset.

INDEX:

```
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form-example></form-example>
  <form-example></form-example>

  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
  <pre>forms = {{forms | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

FORM:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
  E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
  Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
  <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
  <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
</form>
<pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.user = {};
      $scope.forms = [];

    }]);

  angular.module('formExample').directive('formExample', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'form.html',
      scope: {},
      controller: function() {
        $scope.maseter = {};
        $scope.update = function(user) {
          $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
          $scope.forms.push($scope.master);
        };
        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

        $scope.reset();
      }
    }
  });
```

Basically, this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DmyPCeIVcpgpL25B2RQw?p=preview) is a rudimentary concept of what I'm trying to achieve. My biggest problem is that either the ng-clicks don't work, or they only work the first time.

At the moment, ng-model isn't even binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read today, what the Google guidelines on Angular directives say: "use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link."

So, I modified your directive to use link:

```
angular.module('formExample').directive('formExample', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'form.html',
    scope: {
      forms: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.master = {};
      scope.user = {};
      scope.update = function(user) {
        scope.master = angular.copy(scope.user);
        scope.forms.push(scope.master);
      };
      scope.reset = function() {
        scope.user = angular.copy(scope.master);
      };
      scope.reset();
    }
  }
});
```

Notice that the forms are passed to the directive via:

```
<form-example forms="forms"></form-example>
```

For the rest, see [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OIdSu7xMfOGhVSG9ut2o?p=preview).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, @masa, worked exactly how I wanted. I knew there was something in isolating the scope that I was missing. Good to know about the link function also!